# JSON.Net get native type of value

Tags: c#, json, types, json.net

Using JSON.Net, how do I get the native type of a value in a JSON file?  Namely, I'm after simply if it's a string (value enclosed in quotations) or not.

```
var json = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(newVersion.JSON);
foreach (var data in json)
{
    if(data.value IS STRING){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply check the `Type` property of each `JToken` in your list:

```
foreach (var data in json)
{
    if (data.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
        // ...
    }
}
```

See [JTokenType](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm)

Comment: in my case Type gets always == property, I was expecting to see array or object but I just says property

Comment: This property doesn't exist :(

Comment: @AX, What property exactly?

Comment: JToken now has a Type property directly (no longer necessary to go through Value).  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Type.htm. If the property does not exist and you are sure that it's a JToken, maybe you need a cast (e.g. maybe at runtime it is just an 'object' for example and does not know about the 'Type' property).

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649570/how-do-you-check-if-a-json-array-is-an-array-of-objects-or-primitives-recursivel)

Parse the json string via

```
var token = JToken.Parse(content);
```

Make use of JToken to identify its type,

```
if (token is JArray) {

} else if (token is JValue) {

} else if (token is JObject) {

}
```

Comment: What is the type of a byte[] ?